# SQLAlchemy how to create various relationship with backrefs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was reading through the SQLAlchemy documentation on basic relationships and I feel like I'm missing some basic understandings as to how to create the relationship declarations. When I run my code, I'm running into errors such as:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'entity' and 'category'.

sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Entity.categories - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

I thought that the purpose of the relationship() directive was to minimize the creation of manual keys and ids.

I'm also a little confused on the syntax with regards to one-to-many and many-to-many, and many-to-one and how the syntax would differentiate between the different types of relationships.

Heres my example where I create an Entity and various classes around it to try out the various relationships:

```
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False )

    # many-to-one - many entities will belong to one manufacturer
    # do i need to define the mfg_id manually?
    manufacturer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('manufacturer.id'))
    manufacturer = relationship("Manufacturer")

    # one-to-many relationship where an entity will have lots of 
    # properties that belong to it. Each property will only belong to one entity
    properties = relationship("EntityProperty", backref="entity")

    # this is a many-to-many relationship mapping where entity can belong 
    # to multiple categories and you can look up entities by category
    categories = relationship("Category", backref="entities")

class EntityProperty(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity_property'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String(250), nullable=False )
    value = Column(String(250), nullable=False )

    # do we need to define this? or can this be implied by relationship?
    entity_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'))

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False )

    # Does this need to know anything about entities? Many entities 
    # can belong to a category and entities can also belong to multiple
    # categories. Usage is to look up entities that belong to a category.

class Manufacturer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'manufacturer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False )

    # Similar to category except not all manufactures would have entities.
    # How to decouple code at this level from entity
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to learn more about the proper usage of relationship()? Thank you

Comment: Relationships are the ORM mapping over your DBs foreign key references. Without knowing about them SQLAlchemy is at loss how to query for related model objects. You can provide that information manually, but it's rarely useful.

Comment: You also need an associative table between entities and categories in order to have a many to many relationship in SQL, which you'd then map to an ORM relationship. The relationship construct is not meant to minimize definition of keys and ids, but to map an SQL relationship to an ORM one.

Answer (score 1):

First, there has to be a foreign key in the entity table referencing a column in the category table (or vice versa) to establish a relationship. You currently have none.
However, if you intend to have a many-to-many relationship between entity and category then kindly see
[SQLAlchemy many-to-many Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you end up solving your own questions as soon as they are posed. So heres what I learned.

I was getting a little confused with the back_populdate vs backref. I was thinking that if I added a backref I wouldn't need to add the foreignkey in the opposite class, but this was incorrect.

So for the one to many:

This is declared in the Entity

```
properties = relationship("EntityProperty", backref="entity")
```

And this is declared in the EntityProperty to facilitate the necessary back-linking and is required:

```
entity_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("entity.id"))
```

In the many-to-many case, I was missing an association table:

```
cat_entity_association_table = Table("cat_entity_assocaition", Base.metadata,
    Column("category_id", Integer, ForeignKey("category.id")),
    Column("entity_id", Integer, ForeignKey("entity.id")),
)
```

This association is used to construct the bi-directional linking between entities:

```
categories = relationship("Category", secondary=cat_entity_association_table, back_populates="entities")
```

and categories:

```
entities = relationship("Entity", secondary=cat_entity_association_table, back_populates="categories")
```

There was some ambiguity on when to use the external table, but hopefully this will help someone else as well.